# How do I get the schema of all the tables in Hive db using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, hive, database-schema

How do I get the schema of all the tables in Hive db using Python ,

Can I use the "SHOW TABLES" as query like in the following example ? :

```
with pyodbc.connect('DNS = Hive_Connection',autocommit=True) as conn :

    df = pd.read_sql('SHOW TABLES',conn)
```

Thank You (-:

Answer (score 0):

I think the command `SHOW DATABASES` gives you the names of all databases, which are the HIVE equivalent of schemas in other DBMSs.
So the combination of the two commands should allow you to infer the complete name of a table on HIVE.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=Hive_Connection", autocommit=True)
my_databases = """SHOW DATABASES;"""
df_databases = pd.read_sql(my_databases, cnxn)

print(df_databases)

for ind in df_databases.index:
    my_database_tables = "SHOW TABLES IN " + df_databases["database_name"][ind]
    print(my_database_tables)
    df_new
```